# Exim Sender Name

Tags: email, ubuntu, exim

I have ubuntu 12.04 and exim 4.76

I sent email via CLI from root:

```
echo "text" | sendmail 698423@gmail.com
```

and have email with headers (from address)

```
root <root@my-site-address.com>
```

Please, tell me how replace **root** to **myname**:

```
mynaname <myname@my-site-address.com>
```

Comment: `man sendmail` should help.  That is why the manuals exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have logged in with root user so your mail sent from root user. If you want to send from any other user you can switch user as below:

> su - username

ex

> su - myname

replace username with the user from which you want to send mail and send mail with same command.